# how to update libtiff to the latest version in Centos 7?

Tags: linux, centos, libtiff

i want to update libtiff>=4.0.4 in centos7,i try two ways but failed.

first, i used the command

`yum install libtiff`

but the system only have libtiff 4.0.3 that i have installed.

second, i try to install tiff-4.0.9 in local,after i used these command to compile it,it's didn't install successfully and nothing error log showed.

  `./configure
  make
  su
  make install`

i google this question but i can't find solution,anyone can help me,thank you for the first.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of [chemal](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=68296&p=286975#p286975) ,i find the solution:

```
Installation Instructions
For EL7:

cd '/etc/yum.repos.d/'

curl 'https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/scx/libtiff4/repo/epel-7/scx-libtiff4-epel-7.repo' > 'scx-libtiff4-epel-7.repo'     

curl 'https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/scx/rawtherapee/repo/epel-7/scx-rawtherapee-epel-7.repo' > 'scx-rawtherapee-epel-7.repo'

yum install 'rawtherapee'
```

[link](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/scx/rawtherapee/)